# Android : surfaceView cannot getHolder() in onCreate(), must in onResume()

Tags: java, android, layout, surfaceview, surfaceholder

In my activity, I has some views and a `surfaceView`.

Here is my first code in `onCreate()`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    upBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upBtn);
    // and more widget here
    surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);     
    this.holder = surface.getHolder(); // NullPointerException
    setContentView(R.layout.view);
```

If I change the above code by taking `surfaceView` and `getHolder()` in `onResume()` (I have tried many times to have this result), no error:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    upBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upBtn);
    // and more widget here
    // surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView); //cancel     
    // this.holder = surface.getHolder(); // cancel
    setContentView(R.layout.view);
```

---

```
public void onResume() {
    surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);     
    this.holder = surface.getHolder(); // No Error now
```

Please explain for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Becaues you need to call

```
setContentView(R.layout.layoutXML);
```

before you call `findViewById(R.id.viewID)`. that is why your findview by id returning nul, and you probably getting nullPointerException when you are calling surfaceView.getHolder

Suggested solution is, Create a layout.xml file which should have surfaceView inside any layout.

in your Activity's oncreate call     `setContentView(R.layout.layoutXML);` and after this you can retrieve surface view by findViewByID and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: But, except `surfaceView`, I always use `findViewById` before `setContentView` and see no error. Can you tell me more, please.